# Oracle query from pipeline script

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline job, where I'm loading a groovy class and calling a method which has a Oracle database query. In my IDE the class runs fine as I have ojdbc.jar in the classpath. I want to call the method from pipeline script thru groovy, I'm facing the belwo exception. How can I ensure the jar file is referred from the pipeline script.

```
java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source), 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450), 
org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403), 
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method), java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source), 
groovy.sql.Sql.loadDriver(Sql.java:705), groovy.sql.Sql.newInstance(Sql.java:445), 
groovy.sql.Sql$newInstance.call(Unknown Source), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48), 
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:15), 
com.merck.comet.TibcoServiceXML.callSQL(D:\Pedda\Tibco_Automation\src\com\merck\comet\TibcoServiceXML.groovy:58), 
WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:18), 
___cps.transform___(Native Method), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:55), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:106), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:79), 
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor690.invoke(Unknown Source), 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58), 
com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:164), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:297), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$000(CpsThreadGroup.java:78), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:206), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:204), 
org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:47), 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), 
hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112), 
jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28), 
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source), 
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source), 
java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)]
```

Comment: the Exception message from catch block is 'oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource'

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be better to run gradle task which will have dependencies to this lib.

Comment: could you please elaborate.